# Error creating Geoviews quadmesh: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format

Tags: python, holoviews, geoviews

I'm using Geoviews with Python to map weeds in a field. I'm wanting to use a quadmesh to visualize our data similar to the [example on the geoviews website](https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/xarray_quadmesh.html#bokeh-gallery-xarray-quadmesh). I have the following piece of code:

```
d_dict = {
    'Latitude': lats,
    'Longitude': lons,
    'Broadleaf': weed_broadleaf
}

df = pd.DataFrame(pd_dict, columns=pd_dict.keys())
my_ds = gv.Dataset(df, kdims=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], vdims=['Broadleaf'])
my_qmesh = my_ds.to(gv.QuadMesh)
```

Running the code produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/repos/ag-image-import/heatmap_demo.py", line 87, in <module>
    my_qmesh = my_ds.to(gv.QuadMesh)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geoviews/element/__init__.py", line 39, in __call__
    converted = super(GeoConversion, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/__init__.py", line 178, in __call__
    element = new_type(selected, **params)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geoviews/element/geo.py", line 110, in __init__
    super(_Element, self).__init__(data, kdims=kdims, vdims=vdims, **kwargs)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/holoviews/element/raster.py", line 784, in __init__
    super(QuadMesh, self).__init__(data, kdims, vdims, **params)
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    datatype=kwargs.get('datatype'))
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/pygroundskeeper/lib/python3.7/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/interface.py", line 292, in initialize
    raise DataError(error)
holoviews.core.data.interface.DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format.
```

I have tried to convert the data to an XArray dataset instead of a pandas dictionary before reading it into a Geoviews dataset, but that produces the same error.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on the shape of the data? It sounds like it consists of flat 1D arrays which cannot be rendered as a 2D mesh as is.

Comment: Also filed as https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4511 .